# How to define initial, medial, final, and isolated variants in Latin font in FontForge?

Tags: font-forge

I'd like to make a (Latin, English) bitmap-stle cursive font in FontForge.
I want to treat initial, final, medial, and isolated forms of some letters.
I cannot figure out how to get this to work. (Ligatures are working fine).

### Here is a minimal example of what I tried:

###### Make a minimal bitmap font for testing

- Open fontforge and create a new (empty) font.
- `Menu` → `Element` → `Bitmap Strikes Available…` and proceed through the dialog to generate bitmap strikes.
- Double click on the slot for `n` and draw its bitmap.
- `Menu` → `Encoding` → `Add Encoding Slots…`, add 4 slots.
- Double click each of these new slots in turn to open them, and rename them `n.init` `n.medi` `n.fina` `n.isol` using `Menu` → `Element` → `Glyph Info…` and then selecting the `Unicode` sub-dialog from the list on the left, and entering the name into the `Glyph Name:` text box at the top of the window.
- Select `n` in the chracer map, type `ctl`+`c` to copy its bitmap, and type `ctl`+`v` to clone this bitmap into the four slots above. Manually edit each of the `n.init` `n.medi` `n.fina` `n.isol` to be distinctive for debugging purposes (so I can clearly see when they are active).
- Also draw an (empty) bitmap for the space character (we'll use it in testing).

###### Define lookups for initial, medial, final, isolated variants

- `Menu` → `Element` → `Font Info…` then from the list on the left-hand side of the dialog click `Lookups`. The `GSUB` tab should appear on top with some buttons to the right.
- Add the `init` Initial forms lookup table.

  - Click `Add Lookup` on the right hand side, this will open a `Lookup` dialog.
  - From the `Type:` dropdown at the top, select `Single Substitution`.
  - In the `Feature` column of the table below, select the dropdown `∨` next to the `<New>` text and scroll down to `init`
  - Confirm that the `Script(s) & Language(s)` column is populated with `latn{dflt}` (although I also tried `latn{dflt} DFLT{dflt}` for good measure, to no avail).
  - Click `Ok` to finish.
  - Repeat these steps to make lookup tables for the feature types `medi` `fina` and `isol`.
- In the `GSUB` tab of the `Lookups` sub-diaglog, you should now see lists of init/fina/medi/isol types with a `[+]` to the left.
- Click on e.g. `init` and press the `Add Subtable` from the list of buttons on the right of the dialog. Choose a name like `n.init`.

  - In the table column `Base Glyph Name`, click `<New>` and type the glypn name (in this case `n`).
  - In the table column `Replacement Glyph Name`, type `n.init`.
  - Press `Ok` to finish.
  - Repeat these steps similarly for the `fina`, `medi`, and `isol` classes.

###### Test it in the preview window

- To test, we'll bring up the `Print` dialog. On my system this menu optoin is grayed out in the main character map window, but if I bring up the metrics window using `ctl`+`k`, bring it into focus, I can then type `ctl`+`p` to bring this up. We will only use the `Display` tab from this dialog, ignore the `Print` tab.
- Press the radio button `bitmap` to tell it to use the provided bitmaps for font testing.
- Type something like `" n nn nnn nnnn n " to check whether the base, initial, final, medial, or isolate glyph variantes are being used.
- In my case, only the base `n` is ever used.
- Notably, the fina/init/isol/medi rules are not selected in the list in the top left. Clicking on them to try to activate them doesn't seem to do anything.

I installed fontforge from the Ubuntu repositories, here is the output of `fontforge --version`:

```
Copyright (c) 2000-2022. See AUTHORS for Contributors.
 License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 with many parts BSD <http://fontforge.org/license.html>. Please read LICENSE.
 Version: 20201107
 Based on sources from 2022-01-13 19:13 UTC-ML-D-GDK3.
PythonUI_Init()
copyUIMethodsToBaseTable()
fontforge 20201107
build date: 2022-01-13 19:13 UTC
```

### Summary:

I'm trying to define variants for initial/final/medial/isolated for a cursive-esque Latin English bitmap-style font.

Fontforge does not seem to use the defined init/fina/medi/isol rules or the characters bound to them in its `Display` dialog.

I do not think this is a bug in fontforge's `Display` dialog because ligatures (steps not shown) render fine here. It appears that the init/fina/medi/isol rules are just not used.

Indeed, if I go back and add `arab{dflt}` to the `Script(s) & Language(s)` column of a lookup table, then highlighting the test text in the `Display` dialog and typing `arab{dflt}` in the scripts text box above the test area reveals the init/fina/medi/isol forms --- and also changes the text to right-to-left.

So, it seems that the init/fina/medi/isol forms only work in Arabic fonts. Fair enough, but what is the simplest procedure for getting these to be active in a Latin cursive font? I have searched and the tutorials I found so far are mind-bogglingly convoluted.